# How do I replace all . in cell with a blank cell in excel?

Tags: excel, dataset

The following is an example of my dataset:

```
Variable A   B   C    D
         1   0   .    5.4
         0   .   2.8  3.2
         .   1   2    .
```

Here the `.` denotes a blank cell. I want a blank cell to have nothing in it so that it matches up with my other data. When I and replace all `.` with blank then it gets rid of the decimal points also so I cannot do it this way. Is there any way around this? Apologies if my table doesn't make sense. Also, there is over 100,000 cells so changing it manually is not feasible. Thanks!

This is what I want it to look like:

```
Variable A   B   C    D
         1   0       5.4
         0      2.8  3.2
             1   2
```

Comment: Table is supposed to be row-wise with A B C D the headings.

Comment: Do you have a picture maybe? Saying `.` is for blank cells and then saying you're removing `.` to make cells blank is very confusing.

Comment: I edited my question to show you what I want?

Comment: Yes, that's perfect :) Answering in a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a Find and Replace:

Find: `.`

Replace by: Nothing

Click on "Options >>" and check "Match entire cell contents"

Then, replace all.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks so much! :)